# Writing to a Java object during serialization

Tags: java, serialization

Is it safe to update an object during serialization. For instance, while serializing a very large java.util.HashMap, is there a risk that the serialized HashMap is corrupted if during serialization, the HashMap is updated by another thread? So one thread serializes the HashMap while another thread updates the map. By looking at the code for `java.util.HashMap.writeObject` it seems like it might happen.

Comment: By looking at the writeObject-implementation it's not atomic:   
 `s.defaultWriteObject();
 s.writeInt(buckets);
 s.writeInt(size);
 internalWriteEntries(s)` so if for instance after `s.writeInt(size);` is written, another thread updates the map....

Comment: `HashMap` is **not** thread-safe. So anything could occur if multiple threads interact with it. You could get exceptions, or skip elements or whatever. It really depends on the implementation.

Comment: It's not just related to HashMap. I know that HashMap isn't thread-safe. You could look at the implementation for `java.util.ConcurrentHashMap.writeObject` and ask the same question.

Comment: But the implementation of `writeObject` in the CHM is thread-safe. So you can do anything to that map and it won't break the `writeObject` method. But of course an element could be missed. If it was added after a bin has already been traversed.

Comment: What version of Java or where do you find/see/where does it state that the `writeObject` for CHM is thread-safe?

Comment: Fundamentally serialization is just "reading from the object and writing it elsewhere". So if the object isn't thread-safe, so serializing while also writing to the object in some other way is also unsafe. If the object is thread-safe and the serialization code doesn't mess up, then it can be safe. Same as with any other read operation.

Comment: @joachimSauer what is your assesment of e.g. CHM? Would you say it's safe to write to CHM during serialization?